# Picker inside collectionview looses value in SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker, collectionview

I have picker inside Xamarin Forms collectionview, which populated from viewModel. In case of changing index, i.e SelectedIndexChanged event, all pickers loose value and only the last one will be updated to the one which I seleced.
Picker in collectionview,which has 4 rows.

```
<local:CustomPicker x:Name="HoursPicker"
                                        Title="select"
                                        FontSize="14"
                                        Grid.Column="3" 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Hours}"
                                        SelectedIndex="{Binding AmountHour, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                        SelectedIndexChanged="HoursPicker_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"> 
                    </local:CustomPicker>
```

and its my SelectedChangeIndex event

```
  private void HoursPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker picker = (sender) as Picker;
            int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;
            int selectedIndexValue = picker.SelectedIndex + 1;

            ObservableCollection<OrderCardModel> list = new ObservableCollection<OrderCardModel>();
            OrderViewModel vm = new OrderViewModel();
         
            foreach (var item in MyCollectionView.ItemsSource)
            {
                OrderCardModel model = item as OrderCardModel; 
                 
                int changedPrice = 0;
                
                if (selectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    changedPrice = selectedIndexValue * model.Price;
                }
                else
                {
                    changedPrice = model.Price;
                } 
                model.Price = changedPrice; 
                list.Add(model);
                picker.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
                
            }
            MyCollectionView.ItemsSource = list;
        }
```

Comment: is MyCollectionView the CV containing the pickers, or is it a different CV?

Comment: @Jason Yes, CV is containing the pickers.

Comment: when you assign ItemSource in your event handler, you are resetting the CV.  It would make more sense to just update the existing models that the CV is already bound to.

Comment: @Jason but the problem is, UI will not be upadted

Comment: if your models use INotifyPropertyChanged it should

Comment: My ViewModel implements INotifiyPropetyChanged, but I cant access commands, it does not work, thats why I used event handler, and it wouldnt refresh or rebind the UI.

Comment: then you should fix that problem, not use this awkward workaround that is causing even more problems

Comment: The problem is, command works for single picker, but when there are many and wrapped into collection, they dont get right command. I tried assing both command, property and OnPropertychanged, but it wouldnot fire.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out where is the problem. The model, i.e. OrderCardViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
The page (view) binded to the ViewModel, but the collectionview itemsource binded to ObservableCollection of model, even the property comes from view model, but it did not work properly, thatswhy pickers cant respond indexchanging. To do that, model must implement the interface and OnPropertyChanged will update values.